# Understanding a proof that "the columns of a unitary matrix are orthonormal"

Tags: inner-products, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices

**Goal:** Let $u_i$ and $u_j$ be the $i$th and $j$th columns of unitary matrix $U$, respectively.  We wish to show that

$$
\langle u_i, u_j \rangle = 0, i \ne j \\
\langle u_i, u_j \rangle = 1, i = j \\
$$

From pg. 28 of *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, the author presents two proofs of this, the second of which confuses me:

> [image]
>
> [image]

**Question:** Why does showing that

$$
\sum_k U_{ki}^\star U_{kj} = \delta_{ij}
$$

demonstrate the **goal**?  Here it seems that the author is equating

$$
\langle u_i, u_j \rangle
$$

with the complex dot product

$$
u_i \cdot u_k = \sum_k \overline{{u_i}_k} {u_j}_k = \sum_k U_{ki}^* U_{kj}
$$

but aren't those not necessarily always the same thing?

Comment: Are you sure of the page ? is it Dirac $

Comment: @Physor: The author is Shankar, not Dirac.

Comment: What I could understand from you, is that you know that the last equation holds for vectors represented in some orthonoraml basis only, so the question that remains : Does the author represent all  his vectors always in an orthonormal basis?

Comment: In your question "aren't those not necessarily always the same thing" - what specifically does the word **those** refer to? In the setting where you're saying the columns of a unitary matrix are orthonormal, the inner product is assumed to be the "complex dot product" so of course they're the same thing.

Comment: It seams on the page that you posted the author never uses the inner product notation that you use when asking the question. The bra-ket notation, which the author does use, is defined as the 'complex dot product' when expanded w.r.t. an orthonormal basis, so I am curious, are you confused about notation? The author gives an introduction to the notation used earlier in chapter 1. Have you read through this? specifically page 9, eq (1.2.4)?